# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null in postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

when run this code and try to login found this error
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
when iam logging from postman

never found this error in swagger
how to solve that and thanks

```
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userForLoginDto.UserName);
            var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user,userForLoginDto.Password,false);
            if(result.Succeeded){
                var appUser = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
                    u=>u.NormalizedUserName==userForLoginDto.UserName.ToUpper()
                );
                var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(appUser);
                return Ok(new
            {
                token = GenerateJwtToken(appUser).Result,
                user = userToReturn
            });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
            }
```

in swagger
[image]

in postman
[image]

postman screen
[image]

Comment: Show the request you are sending in swagger and postman ... You are seemingly not setting a username in the request ...

Comment: Can you show  your userForLoginDto pls?

Comment: public class UserForLoginDto
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    } @Serge

Answer (score 1):

When you testing in Postman with Post method try to add [FromBody] to the action

```
[HttpPost("login")]
 public async Task<IActionResult>Login([FromBody] UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)

{
   if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( userForLoginDto.UserName) ||
          string.IsNullOrEmpty( userForLoginDto.Password)) return ...error code.
  ....
}
```

and use this input params in your  body>raw>json  of Postman

```
{
  "UserName":"userName",
  "Password": "password"
}
```

Comment: status 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: You have to use body>raw>json in your postman.

Comment: added still found the same error more than applications i don't found that ever

Comment: Maybe it would be usefull if you post a screen shot  of Postman

Comment: @mohamedhemeda Thanks, check Headers too .  application/json; charset=utf-8 option should be checked

Comment: @mohamedhemeda it is really strange. Can you  pls check in debugger if userForLoginDto still has the empty properties?

Comment: many thanks finally working why really i don't know i follow your steps close application and open it again and it's working